# clicked button toggle all the items in the list (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of job descriptions that I want to hide a part of each description and show it completely when a button is clicked using React hooks.

I am iterating over the array( consists of `id` and `description`) to show all the descriptions as a list in the component. There is a button right after each paragraph to show or hide the content.

`readMore` is used to hide/show the content and
`activeIndex` is used to keep track of clicked item index.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Jobs = ({ data }) => {
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

  const job = data.map((job, index) => {
    const { id, description } = job;
    return (
      <article key={id}>
        <p>
          {readMore ? description : `${description.substring(0, 250)}...`}
          <button
            id={id}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveIndex(index);
              if (activeIndex === id) {
                setReadMore(!readMore);
              }
            }}
          >
            {readMore ? "show less" : "show more"}
          </button>
        </p>
      </article>
    );
  });

  return <div>{job}</div>;
};

export default Jobs;
```

The problem is that **when I click one button it toggles all the items** in the list.
I want to show/hide content only when its own button clicked.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you store a *single* boolean value for whether or not to expand the description, called `readMore`. So how would your app know _which one_ to expand? It depends on the behaviour you want. Do you want only one to be open at a time? Or do you want each one to be able to open and close regardless of the state of the others?

Comment: I suggest you separate each item into its own component, this will avoid the problem you are facing, it will also give you more performance when the components re-render.

Comment: @Jayce444 Actually, I want each one to be able to open and close regardless of the state of the others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `readMore` state is entirely redundant and is actually causing the issue. If you know the `activeIndex`, then you have all the info you need about what to show and not show!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Jobs = ({ data }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

  const job = data.map((job, index) => {
    const { id, description } = job;
    return (
      <article key={id}>
        <p>
          {activeIndex === index ? description : `${description.substring(0, 250)}...`}
          <button
            id={id}
            onClick={() => {
              if (activeIndex) {
                setActiveIndex(null);
              } else {
                setActiveIndex(index);
              }
            }}
          >
            {activeIndex === index ? "show less" : "show more"}
          </button>
        </p>
      </article>
    );
  });

  return <div>{job}</div>;
};

export default Jobs;
```

**Edit:** The aforementioned solution only lets you open one item at a time. If you need multiple items, you need to maintain an accounting of all the indices that are active. I think a `Set` would be a perfect structure for this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Jobs = ({ data }) => {
  const [activeIndices, setActiveIndices] = useState(new Set());

  const job = data.map((job, index) => {
    const { id, description } = job;
    return (
      <article key={id}>
        <p>
          {activeIndices.has(index) ? description : `${description.substring(0, 250)}...`}
          <button
            id={id}
            onClick={() => {
              const newIndices = new Set(activeIndices);
              if (activeIndices.has(index)) {
                newIndices.delete(index);
              } else {
                newIndices.add(index);
              }
              setActiveIndices(newIndices);
            }}
          >
            {activeIndices.has(index) ? "show less" : "show more"}
          </button>
        </p>
      </article>
    );
  });

  return <div>{job}</div>;
};

export default Jobs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{readMore && (activeIndex === id) ? description : `${description.substring(0, 250)}...`}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Destination() {
  const travels = [
    {
      title: "Home"
    },
    {
      title: "Traveltype",
      subItems: ["Local", "National", "International"]
    },
    {
      title: "Contact",
      subItems: ["Phone", "Mail", "Chat"]
    }
  ];

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="menu-wrapper">
      {travels.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={`${item.title}`}>
            {item.title}
            {item.subItems && (
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  if (activeIndex) {
                    if (activeIndex !== index) {
                      setActiveIndex(index);
                    } else {
                      setActiveIndex(null);
                    }
                  } else {
                    setActiveIndex(index);
                  }
                }}
              >
                {activeIndex === index ? `Hide` : `Expand`}
              </button>
            )}
            {activeIndex === index && (
              <ul>
                {item.subItems &&
                  item.subItems.map((subItem) => {
                    return (
                      <li
                        key={`li-${item.title}-${subItem}`}
                      >
                        {subItem}
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
              </ul>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add some more description about what your code does